# Как создать проект в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Я никак не могу создать проект в Юнити. Каждый раз он выдает ошибку при создании проекта на любую из платформ. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй Обновить Unity Hub

Comment: Я скачал его с оф сайта. Там по умолчанию последняя версия

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй выбирать не темплейты(проекты которые уже подготовлены чем-то а заходи в Core при создании проекта - и там выбирай измерение, 3D/2D.
Если не поможет - удали unity hub, и скачай заново.
Что-то из этого должно помочь, либо не полностью установился сам движок.
Сам на 2021.3.3 ни разу такого не было